# Why would Rails ignore a migration files when running `rake db:migrate`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a few migration files and for some reasons the `db:migrate` tasks simply ignores one migration file.

```html
class Assets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assets do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :file
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end


end
```

I already tried changing the order of this migration to make sure it runs before any other migrations that require the table it creates.

Comment: what do you mean by "changing the order of this migration"?

Comment: what is the output of "rake db:migrate:status"?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of rake commands:

```
rake db:create          # Create the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:create:all to create all dbs in the config)
rake db:drop            # Drops the database using DATABASE_URL or the current Rails.env (use db:drop:all to drop all databases)
rake db:fixtures:load   # Load fixtures into the current environment's database
rake db:migrate         # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false)
rake db:migrate:status  # Display status of migrations
rake db:rollback        # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n)
rake db:schema:dump     # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load     # Load a schema.rb file into the database
rake db:seed            # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup           # Create the database, load the schema, and initialize with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop the db first)
rake db:structure:dump  # Dump the database structure to db/structure.sql
rake db:version         # Retrieves the current schema version number
```

try `bundle exec rake db:drop:all` which would delete all `migrations` etc and try creating your tables again.